# --version VS -version VS -v

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I have been using linux for some time and whenever I need to find the version of some package, I need to either do --version or -version or -v.

```
python --version
npm -v
```

Also, I have noticed the case where -v is used, we can also use --version and -version.

Comment: So what? Each tool has its own specific command line options which may not be identical for ***all*** the tools you are using..

Comment: I don't see an actual question in your question.

Comment: GNU standard options are with "--", unix default says "-" and BSD tend to prefer just have options (eg. `ps aux`  without any hyphen needed)...  Our system has programs from many different OSes that are all unix or unix-like.  The reason is history  (and whichever historical standard developers most use or prefer...)

Comment: @guiverc thanks, so what I can understand is this that it mostly due to packages from different origins which follows different standards is the main reason behind this small discrepancy

Comment: It's not the packages, but what's inside them (ie. the program author controls the defaults used by that program). You may already have guessed this, just making sure you don't realize it's the Ubuntu/debian packaging (deb/snap) that are involved... Maybe also refer https://xkcd.com/927/ & think history :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the version of an installed package, why don't you simply ask the *package manager*?

```
sh@balrog:~$ dpkg -l python
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                Version        Architecture   Description
+++-===================-==============-==============-===========================================
ii  python              2.7.15~rc1-1   amd64          interactive high-level object-oriented lang
```

```
sh@balrog:~$ apt list python
Listing... Done
python/bionic,now 2.7.15~rc1-1 amd64 [installed]
```

If you don't know what package a program belongs to, again, ask the package manager:

```
sh@balrog:~$ dpkg -l xdpyinfo
dpkg-query: no packages found matching xdpyinfo
```

Duh... that must be in a different package...

```
sh@balrog:~$ dpkg -S $(which xdpyinfo)
x11-utils: /usr/bin/xdpyinfo
```

```
sh@balrog:~$ dpkg -l x11-utils
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                Version        Architecture   Description
+++-===================-==============-==============-===========================================
ii  x11-utils           7.7+3build1    amd64          X11 utilities
```

Comment: I appreciate your descriptive answer and actually got to know a lot of new things, but this is a little off the topic.

Comment: Well, the sad truth is that Open Source developers will do whatever they think is best. You are right that command line options are often inconsistent; some best practices have become a de facto standard, i.e. `-v` and `--version`; but there is also that minority that thinks that `-version` is a good idea (mostly from the X11 world). Yes, that's inconsistent. That's one price to pay for all the diversity and choice the Open Source world gives us.